# Not able to filter files using pathGlobFilter

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

We are trying to read file from directory based on pattern from azure blob srorage.We are using
pathGlobFilter option to select files.  The directory contains following files

```
Sales_51820_14529409_T_7a3cc7d1d17261fd17e7e1fabd3.csv
Sales_51820_14529409_7a3cc7d1d17261fd17e7e1fabd3.csv
Sales_61820_17529409_7a3cc7d1d17261fd17e7e1fabd3.csv
Sales_61820_17529409_T_7a3cc7d1d17261fd17e7e1fabd3.csv
```

We need to process only those files which does  not have "*T*" in file name .We need to process only these two files

```
Sales_51820_14529409_7a3cc7d1d17261fd17e7e1fabd3.csv
Sales_61820_17529409_7a3cc7d1d17261fd17e7e1fabd3.csv
```

But we are not able to read only these two files.
Here is the code,

```
df = spark.read.format("csv").schema(structSchema).options(header=False,inferSchema=True,sep='|',pathGlobFilter= "Sales_\d{5} _ \d{8}_[a-z0-9]+.csv$").load("wasbs://abc@xxxxx.blob.core.windows.net/abc/2022/02/11/"
```

Regards,
Rajib

Answer (score 0):

Glob is not a standard regular expression, there is differences between them.

For example glob doesn't match the number of times.
For details, see:[here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/714503/regular-expressions-vs-filename-globbing)

Back to this question, a relatively stupid way, looking forward to the perfect solution of the giant.

```
pathGlobFilter="Sales_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]_[a-z0-9]*.csv"
```